# jquery faking an ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

To make a nicer experience of a file upload, I am faking an ajax request i.e The user clicks submit, the form dissapears a loading graphic appears and after a view seconds the page refreshs to show their newley upload image.

However since adding the jquery in my file upload always returns the same errors,

You did not select a file to upload. Why is this? This is my form,

```
<div id="picture_upload">
        <div class="loading"></div>
        <?php echo form_open_multipart('my_profile/do_upload'); ?>

        <strong>Choose pictures to upload</strong>
        <p>Max file size: 1MB .jpeg, .gif, .png or .bmp</p>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" />
    </div>
    <!--<div id="webcam_upload">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>-->
</div>
<div id="bottom"><table><tr><td><input type="submit" id="submit_upload" value="Upload a picture" class="button green rounded_5 small" /></td><td>or</td><td><a href="#" id="close_modal" />Cancel</a></td></tr></table></div>
```

and my js,

```
$("#submit_upload").click(function(e){
    //alert("here");
    setTimeout(function() { $("#picture_upload form").submit();}, 6000);
    $("#picture_upload").children().hide();
    $(".loading").show();
    setTimeout( function() {  location=$("#picture_upload form").attr('action') }, 1500 );
    return false;
});
```

The upload function is just your basic upload function from codeigniter.

Comment: Its all nice and good that you provide code, but you missed the part where you handle the upload or were the error message is generated.

Comment: Now that's what I call UX, delaying the upload by six seconds just to show off a spinner!

Comment: Or you could actually upload the file via ajax :) $('#submit_upload').click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); //now do the ajax post of your form instead });

Comment: If I understand you can not upload it again. have not tried to hide the form?

Comment: What is this function `form_open_multipart('my_profile/do_upload');` doing? Post the code here please. I guess it prints out `<form>...</form>` - is that right? If so then Your `<input type="file" ... />` is outside the form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For security reasons You can't upload a file using an XmlHttpRequest object (AJAX).

Alternative solutions are:

- Load your file submission form in an iframe and post that with JS
- Use a flash file uploader
- Use HTML5

Here's a jQuery plugin that appears quite popular: http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: also look into Malsup's ajaxForm plugin. Its what i use all the time.. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
$("#submit_upload").click(function(e){
    //alert("here");
    setTimeout(function() { $("#picture_upload form").submit();}, 6000);
    $("#picture_upload").children().hide();
    $(".loading").show();
    return false;
});
```

And then redirect/reload the page using php

```
header('Location: URL_TO_REDIRECT'); //put it in your end of upload script in php file
```

**If you don't want to redirect from PHP then, you can use**

- jQuery Form plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload
- SWFUpload http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/index.htm
- (there are many libraries for uploading file.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn how to build your own upload using jQuery here is a good article - http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1766159